# Introductory papers in Mirror Symmetry for algebraic geometry students

Tags: algebraic-geometry, self-learning, learning, toric-varieties, mirror-symmetry

Assuming that a student knows algebraic geometry at the level of Cox's

(1) Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms

and

(2) Toric Varieties

What are some good papers (meaning, suitable in light of (1) and (2)) for students to move on to learning the connections of algebraic geometry with mirror symmetry?

Comment: Answers contain some lecture notes on the topic, perhaps, they might be useful. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40062/roadmap-for-mirror-symmetry

Comment: The student also needs to have knowledge of some algebraic topology (homology, cohomology, cap/cup-products, Poincare duality). Also basics of algebraic curves/Riemann surfaces and their moduli spaces (Cox, strangely, ignores both completely). See also suggestions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1962999/prerequisites-for-book-mirror-symmetry-and-algebraic-geometry-by-cox-and-katz?rq=1).